# Editing photos in iOS 8: Allow "YourApp" to modify this photo?

Tags: ios, ios8, photo, photokit, photosframework

In iOS8, using Photos.framework, when you modify a photo using `-[PHPhotoLibrary performChanges:]`, you get the following user dialog:

[image: You know you wanna do it!]

There doesn't seem to be any way around this dialog, and iOS seems to ask every time you save, even to a previously modified (and permitted) photo.

Is there any way to ask for blanket permission to edit photos in iOS8? Other workarounds or help here?

Additional information:

- I'm usually testing this in the simulator. Any known differences here?
- In response to a (possibly now deleted) answer, this assert right before the `-performChanges:` passes:

  ```
  NSAssert([PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus] ==
    PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized, nil)
  ```

Comment: From the docs: "Use this method if you want to add a new asset to the Photos library with edited content” https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phcontenteditingoutput/1624046-initwithplaceholderforcreatedass?language=objc

Answer (score 3):

I found this in the apple documentation
If your app edits the contents of assets already in the Photos library—including assets your app has itself recently added—Photos prompts the user for permission to change the asset’s content. If instead your app uses the initWithPlaceholderForCreatedAsset: method to create an asset with edited content, Photos recognizes your app’s ownership of the content and therefore does not need to prompt the user for permission to edit it.